# install gpg with homebrew

Tags: homebrew, ruby, rvm, gpg

I want to install a new version of `ruby` via `rvm`.
To install that, I need `gnupg2`. I installed it using `brew`, but it could not be linked.

I get the following error message when linking with `brew link gpg2`:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.1.20... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/gpg-agent
Target /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent
is a symlink belonging to gpg-agent. You can unlink it:
brew unlink gpg-agent

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
brew link --overwrite gnupg

To list all files that would be deleted:
brew link --overwrite --dry-run gnupg
```

I have no idea what the `gpg-agent` does and if I can savely overwrite the link without destroying something that my system somewhere needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, macOS does not use anything under `/usr/local`, so yes you can `brew link --overwrite gnupg` safely.

Comment: ok. thanks. but why doesn't brew link it automatically like it normally does?

Comment: Becasue somehow there's already a `/usr/local/bin/gpg-agent` file. Maybe from a past install of gnupg or GPGTools?

Comment: Now it is successfully linked, but after typing `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3` (as written in the manual on https://rvm.io/rvm/install), I get the error message: `gpg: Empfangen vom Schl"usselserver fehlgeschlagen: No route to host`, where the first part is german and means: "Receiving of Keyserver failed". Do you have any idea, what causes this?

Comment: Sounds like a GPG issue, I used to encounter this with GPG on MacPorts but have yet to fix it. Googling around shows some people which managed to fix it.